# What's wrong with enabling a button when any of checkboxes is selected with my implementation with react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks

I have a bug in enabling a button, when any of the checkboxes is selected. Currently it doesnt work on the first click, but only on the second one. Unselecting a checkbox works on the first click also. I think it has something to do with states, but I don't really understand what is causing the problem.

I tried commenting out this line:
`checked.length > 0 ? setTaskBtnsEnabled(true) : setTaskBtnsEnabled(false);`
and it removes the issue so I'm sure it has something to do with the useState. However that line is vital for me so I should come up with a fix for this. I also tried to start with opposite boolean values and the issue remains.

Upper component:

```
const checkedBoxes = () => {
    var checkedOnes = [];
    for (
      var i = 0;
      i < document.getElementsByClassName('count-checkboxes').length;
      i++
    ) {
      if (document.getElementsByClassName('count-checkboxes')[i].checked) {
        checkedOnes.push(
          document.getElementsByClassName('count-checkboxes')[i].parentNode
            .id
        );
      }
    }
    return checkedOnes;
  };

  const [taskBtnsEnabled, setTaskBtnsEnabled] = useState(false);
  const handleBtnsEnabling = event => {
    var checked = checkedBoxes();
    checked.length > 0 ? setTaskBtnsEnabled(true) : setTaskBtnsEnabled(false);
  };
```

Component inside the previous one:

```
<Button
   disabled={!taskBtnsEnabled}
   id="nappi"
>
   OK
</Button>
```

The issue is that first click doesn't work and it doesn't check the checkbox. No error messages coming to console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating one function that each checkbox click will call. This function will increase or decrease the value of a state variable. Something like

```
const [numberOfChecked, setNumberOfChecked] = useState(0)
```

Then add a `useEffect` that will watch for changes to `numberOfChecked`. Inside that hook you could then do your

```
useEffect(() => {
  setTaskBtnsEnabled(numberOfChecked > 0);
}, [numberOfChecked]);
```